# i have dataframe having column -customer i want to elist the details of customer who has occured more than 3 in column instead of boolean series

Tags: pandas, group-by

this is a dataframe having column 'customer' with repetative values

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'customer':['a','b','c','b','b','b','d','e','e','f'],'address':['xx','yy','rr','yy','oo','ee','vv','zz','nn','cc']})

```
want values repeating more than 3 times

df.groupby(['customer']).count()>3
```

result==>
in the result am getting boolean values

```
    id  address
customer        
a   False   False
b   True    True
c   False   False
d   False   False
e   False   False
f   False   False
```

```
expected result==>
    id  customer address
1   2   b     yy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GroupBy.filter()` the dataframe and the `.drop_duplicates` by `"customer"` column:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby("customer")
    .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)
    .drop_duplicates("customer")
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id customer address
1   2        b      yy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby('customer')['customer'].transform('count').gt(3)]
```

Output:

```
   id customer address
1   2        b      yy
3   4        b      yy
4   5        b      oo
5   6        b      ee
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code with `isin`

```
s = df.groupby(['customer'])['id'].count()>3
out = df.loc[df['customer'].isin(s[s].index)]
Out[389]: 
   id customer address
1   2        b      yy
3   4        b      yy
4   5        b      oo
5   6        b      ee
```